# can we compare time fields in SORT card of JCL

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

Suppose I have 12 position of a record holding time field of 8 bytes. Can I compare it with current timestamp? Can I do arithmetic operations on that filed like adding an hour or subtracting few minutes etc. Your responses will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

***Addendum.. for better understanding:***

I need your help in getting time fields compared while writing records from output. 
For instance I have 12th position of the file hloding timestamp of 8bytes. I want to write to output when the timestamp on the record is less than or equal to the current timestamp by an hour. In the process of attaining this i was stuck at below:

```
INCLUDE COND=(12,8,??,GE,&TIME1-1),
```

what could be the data representation (in the place of `??` for this.)

Prior to all can we achieve this using SORT? If so, please gimme SORT card (amend my card if feasible otherwise gimme your version). And also please share the material/repo on time and date comparisons and better handling. Thanks in advance for help.

Regards,
Raja.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Are you trying to compare
data in each record to a timestamp generated for that record during the sort? 
That is a very strange requirement. It would be helpful if you
provided a bit more information here.

Comment: Yes! you are there almost. I have timestamp on each record and that needs to be compared with the one during SORT. To be more clear I have edited the question. Please let me know if you still find any blanks in explanation. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think see what you are trying to do, but have doubts as to whether it will work. These are my thoughts:

- I have only ever seen the **&TIME1(c)** character string used for output. For example: **OUTREC BUILD(1,11,12,&TIME1(:))**
  will place the current time in HH:MM:SS format into the output record starting at position 12. To the
  best of my knowedge, **TIME** cannot be used in an ICETOOL/DFSORT **COND** statement as you have indicated in your question.
- Even if **TIME** were supported within **COND** statements, the +/- operators are not supported as you might
  have seen with **DATE** (eg. **DATE1+1** to get current date plus 1 day). Adding some constant to a **TIME**
  is not supported.
- Have you given any consideration to what would happen if your job were to run a few minutes
  before midnight? Adding an hour to the time causes a roll over to morning of the next day. At that point you
  need to take the date into condideration in the COND.

Something that might work: Add a pre-step to run a REXX, or some other, prgram. Let this program
generate all or part of the
**INCLUDE** statements used in a subsequent ICETOOL step. Here is an example REXX procedure that
will create an **INCLUDE** statement similar to the one given in your question. The record is
written to the file allocated to DD CNTLREC:

```
 /* REXX */
 PULL DELTA  /* Number of hours to add to current time */
 PARSE VALUE TIME('N') WITH HH ':' MM ':' SS /* current time */
 HH = LEFT((HH + DELTA) // 24, 2, '0')  /* add DELTA, check rollover */
 QUEUE " INCLUDE COND=(12,8,CH,GE,C'"HH":"MM":"SS"'),"
 EXECIO * DISKR CNTLREC(FINIS
 EXIT
```

Assign this file to the appropriate ICETOOL control statement DD and it should work for you.

**Warning:** This example does not deal with adjustments that might be
required to the COND parameters in the event of a rollover midnight.

**Note:** If you stored the above REXX procedure in a PDS as: "MY.REXX(FOO)", your pre-step
JCL would look something like:

```
//RUNREXX   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01           
//SYSEXEC  DD DSN=MY.REXX,DISP=SHR  
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=A                  
//SYSTSIN  DD *                         
%FOO
1                               
/*                                      
//
```

The '1' following %FOO is the DELTA number of hours referenced in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you DFSORT is fairly up-to-date, October 2010, DATE5 will have the equivalent of DATE4 but including microseconds, so like a DB2 "timestamp".

```
 OPTION COPY
 INREC OVERLAY=(1:DATE5)
```

gives

```
2013-04-08-19.29.41.261377
```

Comment: oh I'll try that and any idea whether we get the same value without separators? Thanks for your time and interest Bill. :)

Comment: Sorry, only just came across the comment. There are various ways to get rid of the edit characters. If you still need something for this, please edit your question.